# Bootstrap closed.bs.alert doesnt fire when alert is being dynamically created

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a page where I let the user search for information, and it displays an alert at the top stating that he is searching. He is then shown a filtered result. If he clicks the alert dismiss button, the main page is to be reloaded.

However I find that the dismissed event `closed.bs.alert` is never fired.

My javascript code:

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '#mainsearch', function (event) {
        url = window.location.href;
        console.log('Clicked');
        SearchPatients();

    });


    $('body').on('closed.bs.alert', "#srpatalert", function () {
        console.log('Closed alert');
        window.location.href = "/appointments/patients";
    });

    $(function () {
        $('#srpatalert').on('closed.bs.alert', function () {
            console.log('Closed alert');
            window.location.href = "/appointments/patients";
        });
    });


});


function SearchPatients() {
    var srmsgpre = `
    <div id="srpatalert" class="mr-3 alert alert-info alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <strong>Searching For`;
    var srmcl = ' </strong>';
    var srmsgpost = `       
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    `;
    var breadcrumb = `
        <li class="breadcrumb-item">
            <a href="/appointments">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item">
            <a href="/appointments/patients">Patients</a>
        </li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Search results</li>`;

    var srstr = $("#searchterm").val();
    sralmsg = srmsgpre + 'Patients:' + srmcl + srstr + srmsgpost;
    $('#presearch').html(sralmsg);
    return true;
}
```

My html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">   
    <title>Show Patients</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="navbar">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">

        Patients


        </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/appointments">Home
                    <!-- <span class="sr-only">(current)</span> -->
                </a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                    aria-expanded="false">
                    Doctor
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/appointments/doctors">View Doctors</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/appointments/createdoctor">Add Doctor</a>                 

                </div>
            </li>


            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                    aria-expanded="false">
                    Patients
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/appointments/patients">View Patients</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/appointments/createpatient">Add Patient</a>            
                </div>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/appointments/getappointment">Appointments

                </a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Welcome, joel
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/accounts/logout/?next=/appointments/patients">Logout</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My Profile</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/appointments/myappointments">My Appointments</a>
                </div>
            </li>


            <!-- <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li> -->
        </ul>
        <!-- <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0"> -->
            <div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <div id="presearch"></div>
                <input id="searchterm" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button id="mainsearch" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
            </div>
        <!-- </form> -->
    </div>
</nav>

    </div>


    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol id="breadcrumb" class="breadcrumb">

    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
        <a href="/appointments">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
        <a href="/appointments/patients">Patients</a>
    </li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Show Patients</li>

        </ol>
    </nav>


<div id="containerblock" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-3 card-deck">
    <div class="card mb-3 mr-3 ml-3 shadow bg-white rounded" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div id="id" style="display: none;">13 </div>
            <h2 class="card-title">
                <a href="/appointments/patient/13">Epra Peter</a>
                </a>
            </h2>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Age 45</h6>
            <p class="card-text">Mobile 0000</p>
            <p class="card-text">Place </p>
            <div id="docbtngp" class="d-flex flex-row">

                <a href="/appointments/patient/edit/13" class="btn btn-primary mr-1">
                    <i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i>
                </a>            
                <a href="/appointments/patient/calendar/13" class="btn btn-primary mr-1">
                    <i class="fas fa-calendar"></i>
                </a>                
                <a href="/appointments/patient/appointment/add/13" class="btn btn-primary mr-1">
                    <i class="fas fa-calendar-plus"></i>
                </a>


                <a href="/appointments/patient/remove/13" class="btn btn-danger mr-1">
                    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                </a>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3 card-deck">
    <div class="card mb-3 mr-3 ml-3 shadow bg-white rounded" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div id="id" style="display: none;">11 </div>
            <h2 class="card-title">
                <a href="/appointments/patient/11">Jeffy Kelly</a>
                </a>
            </h2>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Age 5</h6>
            <p class="card-text">Mobile 0000</p>
            <p class="card-text">Place </p>
            <div id="docbtngp" class="d-flex flex-row">

                <a href="/appointments/patient/edit/11" class="btn btn-primary mr-1">
                    <i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i>
                </a>            
                <a href="/appointments/patient/calendar/11" class="btn btn-primary mr-1">
                    <i class="fas fa-calendar"></i>
                </a>                
                <a href="/appointments/patient/appointment/add/11" class="btn btn-primary mr-1">
                    <i class="fas fa-calendar-plus"></i>
                </a>


                <a href="/appointments/patient/remove/11" class="btn btn-danger mr-1">
                    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                </a>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3 card-deck">
    <div class="card mb-3 mr-3 ml-3 shadow bg-white rounded" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div id="id" style="display: none;">15 </div>
            <h2 class="card-title">
                <a href="/appointments/patient/15">Ramu Pillai</a>
                </a>
            </h2>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Age 50</h6>
            <p class="card-text">Mobile 0000</p>
            <p class="card-text">Place </p>
            <div id="docbtngp" class="d-flex flex-row">

                <a href="/appointments/patient/edit/15" class="btn btn-primary mr-1">
                    <i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i>
                </a>            
                <a href="/appointments/patient/calendar/15" class="btn btn-primary mr-1">
                    <i class="fas fa-calendar"></i>
                </a>                
                <a href="/appointments/patient/appointment/add/15" class="btn btn-primary mr-1">
                    <i class="fas fa-calendar-plus"></i>
                </a>


                <a href="/appointments/patient/remove/15" class="btn btn-danger mr-1">
                    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                </a>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    <div class="menu pmd-floating-action pmd-lg" role="navigation">
        <a href="/appointments/patient/add" class="pmd-floating-action-btn btn btn-sm pmd-btn-fab pmd-btn-raised pmd-ripple-effect btn-default pmd-lg"
            data-title="Add a new patient">
            <span class="pmd-floating-hidden"></span>
            <i class="material-icons">add</i>
        </a>

    </div>

    <div id="messages">

    </div>
</div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->

    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   

</body>

</html>
```

JSFiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/droidzone/cmw7uszt/)

As you can see above, I tried two different approaches. I'm not able to get the closed.bs.alert event to fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
$(function () {
    $('#srpatalert').on('closed.bs.alert', function () {
        console.log('Closed alert');
        window.location.href = "/appointments/patients";
    });
});
```

with

```
$('#navbar').on('close.bs.alert', '#srpatalert', function () {
  console.log('Closed alert');
  window.location.href = "/appointments/patients";
});
```

Notice that, besides delegating the event to `#navbar`, I also changed the event itself (from `closed.bs.alert` to `close.bs.alert`) as `closed.bs.alert` doesn't seem to fire in this example - I don't know why and, since it's working with `close.bs.alert`, I didn't investigate further.

Here's a working example:

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  $('body').on('click', '#mainsearch', function(event) {
    url = window.location.href;
    console.log('Clicked');
    SearchPatients();

  });

  $('#navbar').on('close.bs.alert', "#srpatalert", function() {
    console.log('Closed alert');
  });

  // don't mind next line, it's just for SO:
  $(document).on('click', 'a', e => e.preventDefault())
});

function makeAlert(category, term) {
  return $('<div />', {
    id:'srpatalert',
    class:'mr-3 alert alert-info alert-dismissible fade show',
    role: 'alert'
  }).append($('<strong />',{text:'Searching For ' + category + ': '}))
    .append($('<span />', {text: term}))
    .append($('<button />', {
        type:'button',
        class:'close',
        'data-dismiss':'alert',
        'aria-label':'Close',
        html: $('<span />',{
          'aria-hidden':true,
          html:'&times;'
        })
      }))
}

function SearchPatients() {
  sralmsg = makeAlert('Patients', $("#searchterm").val());
  $('#presearch').html(sralmsg);
  return true;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      Patients
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/appointments">Home
                    <!-- <span class="sr-only">(current)</span> -->
                </a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Doctor
                </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/appointments/doctors">View Doctors</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/appointments/createdoctor">Add Doctor</a>

          </div>
        </li>


        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Patients
                </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/appointments/patients">View Patients</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/appointments/createpatient">Add Patient</a>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/appointments/getappointment">Appointments

                </a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Welcome, joel
                </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/accounts/logout/?next=/appointments/patients">Logout</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My Profile</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/appointments/myappointments">My Appointments</a>
          </div>
        </li>


        <!-- <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li> -->
      </ul>
      <!-- <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0"> -->
      <div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <div id="presearch"></div>
        <input id="searchterm" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button id="mainsearch" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
      </div>
      <!-- </form> -->
    </div>
  </nav>

</div>


<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
  <ol id="breadcrumb" class="breadcrumb">

    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
      <a href="/appointments">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
      <a href="/appointments/patients">Patients</a>
    </li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Show Patients</li>

  </ol>
</nav>


<div id="containerblock" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-3 card-deck">
      <div class="card mb-3 mr-3 ml-3 shadow bg-white rounded" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div id="id" style="display: none;">13 </div>
          <h2 class="card-title">
            <a href="/appointments/patient/13">Epra Peter</a>
          </h2>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Age 45</h6>
          <p class="card-text">Mobile 0000</p>
          <p class="card-text">Place </p>
          <div id="docbtngp" class="d-flex flex-row">

            <a href="/appointments/patient/edit/13" class="btn btn-primary mr-1">
              <i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="/appointments/patient/calendar/13" class="btn btn-primary mr-1">
              <i class="fas fa-calendar"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="/appointments/patient/appointment/add/13" class="btn btn-primary mr-1">
              <i class="fas fa-calendar-plus"></i>
            </a>


            <a href="/appointments/patient/remove/13" class="btn btn-danger mr-1">
              <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
            </a>


          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3 card-deck">
      <div class="card mb-3 mr-3 ml-3 shadow bg-white rounded" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div id="id" style="display: none;">11 </div>
          <h2 class="card-title">
            <a href="/appointments/patient/11">Jeffy Kelly</a>
          </h2>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Age 5</h6>
          <p class="card-text">Mobile 0000</p>
          <p class="card-text">Place </p>
          <div id="docbtngp" class="d-flex flex-row">

            <a href="/appointments/patient/edit/11" class="btn btn-primary mr-1">
              <i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="/appointments/patient/calendar/11" class="btn btn-primary mr-1">
              <i class="fas fa-calendar"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="/appointments/patient/appointment/add/11" class="btn btn-primary mr-1">
              <i class="fas fa-calendar-plus"></i>
            </a>


            <a href="/appointments/patient/remove/11" class="btn btn-danger mr-1">
              <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
            </a>


          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3 card-deck">
      <div class="card mb-3 mr-3 ml-3 shadow bg-white rounded" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div id="id" style="display: none;">15 </div>
          <h2 class="card-title">
            <a href="/appointments/patient/15">Ramu Pillai</a>
          </h2>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Age 50</h6>
          <p class="card-text">Mobile 0000</p>
          <p class="card-text">Place </p>
          <div id="docbtngp" class="d-flex flex-row">

            <a href="/appointments/patient/edit/15" class="btn btn-primary mr-1">
              <i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="/appointments/patient/calendar/15" class="btn btn-primary mr-1">
              <i class="fas fa-calendar"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="/appointments/patient/appointment/add/15" class="btn btn-primary mr-1">
              <i class="fas fa-calendar-plus"></i>
            </a>


            <a href="/appointments/patient/remove/15" class="btn btn-danger mr-1">
              <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
            </a>


          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="menu pmd-floating-action pmd-lg" role="navigation">
      <a href="/appointments/patient/add" class="pmd-floating-action-btn btn btn-sm pmd-btn-fab pmd-btn-raised pmd-ripple-effect btn-default pmd-lg" data-title="Add a new patient">
        <span class="pmd-floating-hidden"></span>
        <i class="material-icons">add</i>
      </a>

    </div>

    <div id="messages">

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: That's almost the approach I took in the lines just before those. Only I used `body` instead of `document`

Comment: I'll create a fiddle with your code and see why it doesn't work

Comment: @Droid, do you actually have line breaks inside JavaScript strings?

Comment: For ease of seeing html structure, I enclose them in ``` quotes

Comment: Added a [mcve] to my answer. Turns out you were hooking the wrong event: it's `close.bs`, not `closed.bs`.

Comment: @Droid, I rewrote `SearchPatients()` as an alternative.

Comment: @tao - those are two different events. `closed.bs` fires after the alert is closed.  it's perfectly valid.

Comment: @billy, I never said it's invalid. But I noticed in the specific example of the question it doesn't fire. Which is why it's the accepted answer. The least you could do before down-voting an answer would be to actually test it in the context it was provided for. In OP's case, `closed.bs.alert` is not fired, even when bound on parent. If you have a better answer, feel free to post it.

Comment: I did (test) and perhaps it's my version of bootstrap, but for me *neither of those events* bubbles up the DOM. So your answer doesn't work regardless.  I'm not saying it didn't work for you - maybe both question and answer need to specify boostrap version.  There's a comment [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12379#issuecomment-265788484) which seems to hint at why this might have come about.

Comment: your statement "it's close.bs.alert, not closed.bs.alert" seems to indicate that the latter is not a valid boostrap event. Sorry if I misunderstood, I'll retract my downvote but can you please clarify on the difference between those two events and why it matters in the context of your answer?  at any rate, my vote is locked until an edit is made.

Comment: @billynoah, my statement was drawing attention on the fact I also changed the event, besides the context (it's a change that could be easily overlooked). Regarding your own issue, I can't answer it here. Please ask a new question, link this one and specify it doesn't work in your case and I might be able to help. Also please include an [mcve] as fixing this type of errors is almost impossible without one.

Comment: @billy, ref changing context: the initial code was binding to the alert element, ***which has to be in DOM at the time of binding***, otherwise no binding is done, as there is no target. Instead, I bound on the parent which exists in DOM at the time of binding. So it will work for current and future alerts in that parent. Read more on delegated event handlers [here](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) and [here](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Comment: @billy, I wish I could help without being able to inspect it, but I really can not.

Comment: @tao - Sorry didn't notice your edit before and I've reversed my downvote.  If you look at the bootstrap source you will see something like `$parent.detach().trigger('closed.bs.alert').remove()` for `closed` event which prevents any delegated event from bubbling

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in comments on the accepted answer above, the `closed` event does not properly bubble even if you use a delegated event and attach the handler to parent. A bit of discussion on this [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12379#issuecomment-265788484).

Also, it's important to note that there is a distinct difference between `close` and `closed`, which is that the latter fires *after* the alert has been removed. In some applications this difference may be significant, such as when you need to resize other elements based on changes to the dom.

With that in mind, if you **absolutely need to use the `closed` event**, you must dynamically add your handler anytime the alert is created. This could be done in your example code immediately after:

```
$('#presearch').html(sralmsg);
```

You could add your handler so it would look like this:

```
$('#presearch').html(sralmsg);
$('#srpatalert').off().on('closed.bs.alert', function () {
    console.log('Closed alert');
    window.location.href = "/appointments/patients";
});
```